# Is such access-refresh token authorization schema without addressing to database safe?

Tags: authentication, security, jwt, authorization, ip

So here is the modification of jwt access-refresh authorization schema without addressing database I come up with:

1. We store ip-address and device type in jwt refresh token, then ***encrypt*** the token.
2. Let's imagine malicious user hijacks the refresh token. The malicious user doesn't know anything about content of such refresh token as it is some encrypted string.
3. He wants to receive a new refresh token and sends us the hijacked one.
4. We decrypt the token, extract ip-address and device type from the token and compare with ip-address and device type of request. If they were equal, then we know it is request from authorized user and we give him new refresh token, otherwise it is request from malicious user and we reject the request.

Is there any pitfalls with such authorization schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting the refresh token is a good idea. It is a way of changing the JWT token into an opaque one, without the need for a database. It's also convenient that the token will be decrypted only by the authorization server, so there is no need to distribute any keys.

As for rejecting tokens with a different IP — that actually depends on your system and the characteristics of your users. A user's IP number can change even when it's not a malicious action. E.g., the user might switch to a different wifi or turn on VPN protection and will get a new IP number. Many routers are also assigned a new IP on every connection to the ISP, so the IP number can sometimes change even when the user does not change their location or network settings. If you know that this will not happen to your users and that they should always operate under the IP that they logged in from (maybe you have a system that is only meant for employees connecting from a concrete VPN), then that approach might be ok.

You would also need mechanisms in place that will protect against spoofing IP information. The same goes for the device type. You would have to make sure that you have a reliable source of information for the type of device, and that that information cannot be spoofed.

Comment: MAC address would be perfect option here instead of ip-address. But unfortunately they are not transmitted